# Column Headers to the last line of data entered to the HTMLBody

Tags: html, excel, vba, automation

I've included the last line of data entered to my HTML body. However the column headers are not showing, what am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub cmdEmail_Click()

    'Declare Outlook Variables
    Dim OLApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OLMail As Object
    Dim MyData As Object
    'Open the Outlook Application and Start a new mail
    Set OLApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OLMail = OLApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set MyData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, 13)
    OLApp.Session.Logon
    With OLMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Quality Alert"
        .HTMLBody = "<P><font size='6' face='Calibri' color='black'>Quality Issue Found<br><br> Please reply back with what adjustments have been made to correct this issue. </font></P>" & ConvertRangeToHTMLTable(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, 13))
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
        Dim wb As Workbook
        ws.Copy
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        wb.SaveAs "C:\Temp\Database.xlsx" 'Change Path
        .Display
        ' .Send
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Kill "C:\Temp\Database.xlsx"
    End With
    
    'Clearing Memory
    
    Set OLMail = Nothing
    Set OLApp = Nothing 
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the 1st 13 columns of the last row are being targeted.

> ```
> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, 13)
> ```

I order to include all the data, you'll have to extend the range from the first cell to the last row.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
    Set MyData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, 13))
End With
```

Breaking up the code into smaller bites will allow you to easily isolate and test your code.

Extracting the code that targets the data range into its own function (in a public module) allows use `Application.Goto` to visibly inspect the range.

> ```
> Application.Goto EmailData
> ```

```
Private Sub cmdEmail_Click()
    Dim HTMLBody As String
    HTMLBody = EmailHTMLFirstAndLastRow

    SendEmail HTMLBody 
    CreateACopyOfTheDatabaseSaveItCloseKillItButNeverDoAnythingWithit
End Sub
```

Place this code in a public module:

```
Sub SendEmail(HTMLBody As String)
    'Declare Outlook Variables
    Dim OLApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OLMail As Object
    Dim MyData As Object
    'Open the Outlook Application and Start a new mail
    Set OLApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OLMail = OLApp.CreateItem(0)
    OLApp.Session.Logon
    
    With OLMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Quality Alert"
        .HTMLBody = "<P><font size='6' face='Calibri' color='black'>Quality Issue Found<br><br> Please reply back with what adjustments have been made to correct this issue. </font></P>" & HTMLBody
         .Display
        ' .Send
    End With
    'Clearing Memory
    
    Set OLMail = Nothing
    Set OLApp = Nothing
    
End Sub

Function EmailHTMLFirstAndLastRow() As String
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = EmailData
    
    With Target
        .EntireRow.Hidden = msoTrue
        .Rows(1).Hidden = msoFalse
        .Rows(.Rows.Count).Hidden = msoFalse
        .EntireRow.Hidden = msoFalse
    End With
    EmailHTMLFirstAndLastRow = RangetoHTML(Target.Rows(Target.Rows.Count))
End Function

Function EmailData() As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
        Set EmailData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, 13))
    End With
End Function

Sub CreateACopyOfTheDatabaseSaveItCloseKillItButNeverDoAnythingWithit()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    Dim wb As Workbook
    ws.Copy
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    wb.SaveAs "C:\Temp\Database.xlsx" 'Change Path
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Kill "C:\Temp\Database.xlsx"
End Sub
```

### Edit

I edited the code to create html for only the header and last rows, as per the OP's request.  Since `RangetoHTML()` ignores hidden rows, I define the range of data, hid all but the fist and last rows, the passed the range to `RangetoHTML()` and assigned its value to a variable, the unhid the range.

Comment: Well see that the thing I need to keep the Column Header and only add the last line of data entered not the whole Database. So when multiple ppl enter in data the header stays and the data under the header is the data they just added only. as a single line.

Comment: @TheRabbit the easiest thing to do is copy them to a temp worksheet for use with the email.

Comment: strReturn = "<Table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='7' style='border-collapse:collapse;border:none'>  "
    'Loop through each row in the range                                 so I wrote this into my ConvertRangeToHTMLTable . How can i add the column header into this module as its built into the HTML Body

Comment: @TheRabbit I modified my answer.  `RangetoHTML()` ignores hidden rows.  Basically define the complete range, hide what you don't want to send out and then use `RangetoHTML()` .